# Installing podman 4.1 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, podman

I found instructions on various sites for installing podman on Ubuntu 20.04:

https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-podman-on-ubuntu/

https://www.atlantic.net/dedicated-server-hosting/how-to-install-and-use-podman-on-ubuntu-20-04/

However, all of the instructions I have found result in podman 3.4.2 being installed.

How do I install 4.1 (the latest, at the time of of this writing) instead?

Comment: Doubt it will be easy, maybe even impossible – podman will probably depend on newer aspects of cgroups2, which the Ubuntu 20.04 might simply not have, predating that. Is there a particular reason you're not using the current long-term support release of Ubuntu, Ubuntu 22.04LTS, for this, or a distro to which `podman` is more "native" (Ubuntu historically was a LXD shop, Canonical had to go alone on that, and later was more friendly to Docker than podman)? (These distros with excellent podman support would be Fedora, and for servers Redhat, Rocky Linux or AlmaLinux.)

Comment: Even with [Ubuntu 22.04 there's no proper way of installing Podman 4.x](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414446/whats-the-recommended-way-of-installing-podman-4-in-ubuntu-22-04).